# Changing individual line chart series color JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a window that has three different line charts in it. I am trying to set the color of each line chart series individually. Right now I have a css file that has something like this:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: blue }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: black }
```

What this does is set the colors of series in each chart. For example, if I have a line chart that has two series, one would be blue, the other would be black. But with this setting, all three charts with one series default to blue.

What I am trying to achieve is setting the series individually, so that my first line chart has someColor1, the second line chart has someColor2, etc.

I have tried many things, and searched all over the internet, but I have either seen "guesses" which do not work, or ways to set the default through css. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

I am trying to set the style using `lineChart.setStyle("-fx-stroke: green");` for example.

Comment: Set `id`s on the charts, so that you can reference each one individually in the CSS file...

Comment: Oh ok! I wasn't aware that you could do that.

Comment: I guess "searching all over the internet" didn't include reading the actual [tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG) ;)

Comment: I actually did, several times. But I didn't see that. I only saw the default-color setting. Maybe I was looking in the wrong place. Id say the limiting factor was that I was searching how to change a series color, not how to link css to an id. Although I should have thought to look for that.

Comment: Fair enough :). See if the code posted in the answer works.

Answer (score 3):

To reference nodes individually (instead of grouped by class) in a CSS file, you need to add an `id` to the node:

```
LineChart<Number, Number> chart1 =  ... ;
LineChart<Number, Number> chart2 =  ... ;
LineChart<Number, Number> chart3 =  ... ;

chart1.setId("chart1");
chart2.setId("chart2");
chart3.setId("chart3");
```

Obviously, you can choose more meaningful ids that describe what each chart is.

Then in your CSS you can do

```css
#chart1 .chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: blue }
#chart2 .chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: black }
#chart3 .chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: green }
```

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm. I appreciate your help!